# DataDog metrics aren't working for my python application running on lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, datadog

I referred to a few docs on DataDog's website and it's still not collecting any metrics and sending them to DataDog. The function executes perfectly and I thought I configured everything correctly but it's not working.

Here's my application code that includes the required modules and the function "wrapper" it mentions to put above my lambda function module

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
import os
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime
from datadog_lambda.metric import lambda_metric
from datadog_lambda.wrapper import datadog_lambda_wrapper

lat = '33.4483771'
lon = '-112.0740373'
exclude = 'minutely,hourly,alerts'

url = (
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?' +
    'lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={exclude}&appid={API_key}&units=imperial'
)

if os.path.isfile('.env'):
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv()

def __send_email(msg: str) -> None:
    gmail_user = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')
    gmail_password = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')

    mail_from = gmail_user
    mail_to = gmail_user

    mail_subject = f'Weather Today {datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}'
    mail_message = f'Subject: {mail_subject}\n\n{msg}'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, mail_message)
    server.close()

@datadog_lambda_wrapper
def handler(event, context):
    response = requests.get(url.format(
        lat=lat,
        lon=lon,
        exclude=exclude,
        API_key=os.getenv('WEATHER_API_KEY')
    ))

    data = response.json()

    rain_conditions = ['rain', 'thunderstorm', 'drizzle']
    snow_conditions = ['snow']

    today_weather = data['daily'][0]['weather'][0]['main'].lower()

    if today_weather in rain_conditions:
        msg = 'Pack an umbrella!'
    elif today_weather in snow_conditions:
        msg = 'Pack your snow boots!'
    else:
        msg = 'Clear skies today!'

    __send_email(msg) 

        # submit a custom metric
    lambda_metric(
        metric_name='coffee_house.order_value',
        value=12.45,
        tags=['product:latte', 'order:online']
    )
    
handler(None, None)
```

I created a lambda layer with the correct ARN found from their website

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Python37:56
```

I also added a variable for my function called DD_API_KEY as per the docs and used my API key for it. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Update:

Including function log:

```
START RequestId: 7370df11-49d7-4759-a8e4-eff2916a620a Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog_lambda/wrapper.py", line 156, in _before
submit_invocations_metric(context)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog_lambda/metric.py", line 124, in submit_invocations_metric
submit_enhanced_metric("invocations", lambda_context)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog_lambda/metric.py", line 112, in submit_enhanced_metric
tags = get_enhanced_metrics_tags(lambda_context)
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog_lambda/tags.py", line 87, in get_enhanced_metrics_tags
return parse_lambda_tags_from_arn(lambda_context) + [
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog_lambda/tags.py", line 37, in parse_lambda_tags_from_arn
split_arn = lambda_context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invoked_function_arn'
/opt/python/botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:67: DeprecationWarning: You are using the get() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'.  This is not a public API in botocore and will be removed in the future. Additionally, this version of requests is out of date.  We recommend you install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.get() function instead.
DeprecationWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog_lambda/wrapper.py", line 190, in _after
status_code = extract_http_status_code_tag(self.trigger_tags, self.response)
AttributeError: '_LambdaDecorator' object has no attribute 'trigger_tags'
{"m": "aws.lambda.enhanced.invocations", "v": 1, "e": 1649914335, "t": ["region:us-west-2", "account_id:775362094965", "functionname:DataDog", "resource:DataDog", "cold_start:false", "memorysize:128", "runtime:python3.7", "datadog_lambda:v3.56.0", "dd_lambda_layer:datadog-python37_3.56.0"]}
/opt/python/botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:67: DeprecationWarning: You are using the get() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'.  This is not a public API in botocore and will be removed in the future. Additionally, this version of requests is out of date.  We recommend you install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.get() function instead.
DeprecationWarning
END RequestId: 7370df11-49d7-4759-a8e4-eff2916a620a
```

Comment: Can you upload lambda logs?

Comment: @FranxiHidro Just added the most recent log to the post, sorry for the delayed response

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess it's the wrong type. Can you remove **metric_name=** and **value=** in *lambda_metric* and run it again?

Comment: @FranxiHidro I took out those two lines and it returned this error message "errorMessage": "2022-04-14T07:38:13.805Z 15ba04e4-ef27-45ca-a129-7434d8236e53 Task timed out after 3.04 seconds"

Comment: Don't remove 2 lines, just remove **metric_name=** and **value=**, keep the values 'coffee_house.order_value' and 12.45; like this:  ``lambda_metric(
        'coffee_house.order_value',
        12.45,
        tags=['product:latte', 'order:online']
    )``

Comment: @FranxiHidro The function executed again after fixing that, but still not receiving any metrics unfortunately

Comment: Last try :), can you create another test function using the below code (copied from dd: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/datadog-lambda-layer/ ). It should work.

```from datadog_lambda.metric import lambda_metric


from datadog_lambda.wrapper import datadog_lambda_wrapper

@datadog_lambda_wrapper

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_metric(
        "coffee_house.order_value",             # Metric name
        12.45,                                  # Metric value
        tags=['product:latte', 'order:online']  # Associated tags
    )```

Comment: @FranxiHidro ahhhh I forgot to set the DD_TRACE_ENABLED environment variable and doing that did the trick. Really appreciate the help to try to get this working